# Schema for Inspection/Exam Questions/Answers with scoring

Tags: database, database-design, schema, database-schema

I'm writing an application that will generate inspections for our locations.  Basically, think of them as health inspection forms.  Each "inspection" will have a series of questions and answers.  The answers can be either numeric (1,2,3,4,5 - which will represent their point values), or multiple choice ('Yes','No') that will have map to points (1 for yes, 0 for no) and flat text answers that will not map to points but might be able to be used by the application layer for averaging.  So for example, we could have a field for "Sauce Temperature" which carries no points, but could be used for reporting down the road.

Questions can be reused on multiple inspection forms but can have different point values.  So can answers.

I'm having trouble figuring out the schema for this.  My instinct says EAV would be a good way to go, but the more I think about it, the more I'm thinking more of a data warehouse model would be better.

Particularly, I'm having a problem figuring out the best way to map the min_points, max_points and no_points to each question/answer.  This is where I am thinking I'm going to have to use EAV.  I'm kind of stuck on it actually.  If it was a survey or something where there were no points, or the same point value for each answer, it would be pretty simple.  Question table, answer table, some boilerplate tables for input type and so forth.  But since each question MAY have a point value, and that point value may change depending on which location is using that question, I'm not sure how to proceed.

So, the example questions are as follows

- Was the food hot [Yes, No] Possible points = 5 (5 for yes, 0 for no)
- Was the food tasty [1,2,3,4,5] Possible points = 5 (1 for 1, 2 for 2, etc)
- Was the manager on duty [Yes, No] Possible points = 5 (5 for yes, 0 for no)
- Was the building clean [1,2,3,4,5] Possible Points = 10 (2 for 1, 4 for 2, 6 for 3, etc)
- Was the staff professional [Yes, No] Possible Points = 5 (5 for yes, 0 for no)
- Freezer Temp [numerical text input]
- Manager on duty [text input]

Since all the answers can have different data types and point values I'm not sure how to build out the database for them.

I'm thinking (Other tables, names and other imp details left out or changed for brevity)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inspection(
id mediumint(8) unsigned not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
store_id mediumint(8) unsigned not null,
inspection_id mediumint(8) unsigned not null,
date_created datetime,
date_modified timestamp,
INDEX IDX_STORE(store_id),
INDEX IDX_inspection(inspection_id),
FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (store_id)ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (inspection_id) REFERENCES inspection (inspection_id)ON DELETE CASCADE)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS input_type(
input_type_id tinyint(4) unsigned not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
input_type_name varchar(255),
date_created datetime,
date_modified timestamp)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inspection_question(
question_id mediumint(8) unsigned not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
question text,
input_type_id mediumint(8),
date_created datetime,
date_modified timestamp)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inspection_option(
option_id,
value)
```

But here's where I'm kind of stuck.  I'm not sure how to build the question answers tables to account for points, no points, and different data types.

Also, I know I'll need mapping tables for stores to inspections and so forth, but I've left those all off for now, since it's not important to the question.

So, should I make a table for answers where all possible answers (built from either the options table or entered as text) are stored in that table and then a mapping table to map an "answer" to a "question" (for any particular inspection) and store the points there?

I'm just not thinking right.  I could use some help.

Comment: A well written question +1. I have a few in return :-). Why does "Was the building clean have 10", generally will the number of point values _ever_ change from 1-5? Also, why is freezer temp a "numerical text"; won't it always be a number?

Comment: @Ben "Was the building clean" would have as options 1-5 but the question would be worth 10 points because that's it's weight in the inspection.  It's 10% of an inspection grade, but I don't want people to have to answer between 1-10, and would rather have them answer 1-5.  (this is an oversimplified example, no such question exists, but the point is still the same) By numerical text, I mean they'll have to key it into the answer field, as opposed to multiple chose questions (yes, no, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc) which will likely be radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no right or wrong answer here, I’m just tossing out some ideas and discussion points.

I would propose that the basic “unit” isn’t the question, but the pair of question + answer *type* (e.g. 1-5, text, or whatever). Seems to me that `Was the food hot / range 1 to 5` and `Was the food hot / text description` are so very different you’d go nuts trying to relate a question with two (or more) answer types (let alone answer keys for those answers--ignore that for now, I pick up on that later). Call the pair a QnA item. You may end up with a lot of similar pairs, but hey, it's what you've got to work with.

So you have a “pool” of QnA items. How are they selected for use? Are specific forms (or questionnaires) built from items in the pool, or are they randomly selected every time a questionnaire is filled out? Are forms specifically related to location, or might a form be used at any location? How fussy are they at building their forms/questionnaires? How the QnA items are collected/associated with one another and/or there ultimate results is pretty important, and you should work it all out before you start writing code, unless you really like rewriting code.

Given a defined QnA item, you should also have an “answer key” for that item – a means by which a given answer (as based on the item's answer type) measured: Zero, Value, Value * 2, whatever. This apparently can vary from usage to usage (questionnaire to questionnaire? Does it differ based on the location at which the questionnaire is presented? If so, how or why?) Are there standardized answer key algorithms (alwyas zero, always Value * 2, etc) or are these also extremely free-form? Determining how they are used/associated with the QnA items will be essential for proper modeling.

Comment: Inspections are built per store and each store will have multiple inspections.  The questions will be set per inspection.  So, as an admin user, I'd create an inspection form and populate it with questions and answers from a q/a pool.  On any given inspection form, a question might have a different point potential depending on the inspection for it's being used on.  I hope that gives you a better idea.  I've got all the requirements figured out, and am just now trying to figure out the implementation.  I'm not writing code yet, as I've not been able to figure out how to do it schema wise.

Comment: Also, I suppose you're right about having to make duplicate QA pairs, to be able to handle the scoring.  Didn't really think about that, particularly if I were going to make answer keys with weights and scores.  Still, it feels like there's a cleaner model for this.  I know it's not a new problem.